# Game theory model with multiple, known ESSs?

Tags: game-theory

I'm looking for examples of evolutionary game theory models, hopefully but necessarily biologically-inspired, with multiple known ESSs (evolutionarily stable strategies) for the purposes of testing some software.  When I say "known", I mean that the ESS solutions have been worked out, not just proven to exist.  I'd prefer published models that I can reference, but in a pinch I'll take what I can get! :)

Comment: Okay, well, I was hoping for more examples but I appreciate Ricky's taking the time to answer so I'll accept that one. :-)  But I'd still love any other answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payoffs are 1 if the strategies are the same and 0 otherwise.

If you want a continuous strategy space, you can have the payoffs be a "location bonus" (that depends only on the player's own strategy) minus some strictly increasing function of the distance between the players' strategies.  Any strategy that maximizes the location bonus will be an evolutionarily stable strategy.

(I now notice that the first example is equivalent to the special case of the second where the location bonus is constant and the metric is the [discrete metric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteMetric.html).)

Comment: Thanks, Ricky!  That's a great simple example. I'm also hoping to find an example of something a little more interesting to a biological crowd. :-)